# How to locally access an Ollama model remotely hosted on a Google Colab for a Python script?

Tags: python, json, google-colaboratory, ollama

I am able to successfully run Ollama on Google Colab using this code (below), and am able to access it from my local terminal using `export OLLAMA_HOST=https://{url}.ngrok-free.app/` and `ollama run llama2`.

```
from google.colab import userdata
NGROK_AUTH_TOKEN = userdata.get('NGROK_AUTH_TOKEN')

# Download and install ollama to the system
!curl https://ollama.ai/install.sh | sh

!pip install aiohttp pyngrok

import os
import asyncio

# Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH so the system NVIDIA library
os.environ.update({'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/usr/lib64-nvidia'})

async def run_process(cmd):
  print('>>> starting', *cmd)
  p = await asyncio.subprocess.create_subprocess_exec(
      *cmd,
      stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
      stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
  )

  async def pipe(lines):
    async for line in lines:
      print(line.strip().decode('utf-8'))

  await asyncio.gather(
      pipe(p.stdout),
      pipe(p.stderr),
  )

#register an account at ngrok.com and create an authtoken and place it here
await asyncio.gather(
    run_process(['ngrok', 'config', 'add-authtoken', NGROK_AUTH_TOKEN])
)

await asyncio.gather(
    run_process(['ollama', 'serve']),
    run_process(['ngrok', 'http', '--log', 'stderr', '11434']),
)
```

However, I'm not able to use a locally executed Python script to access the Google Colab Ollama. Here is the code I have tried:

```
import requests

# Ngrok tunnel URL
ngrok_tunnel_url = "https://{url}.ngrok-free.app/"

# Define the request payload
payload = {
    "model": "llama2",
    "prompt": "Why is the sky blue?"
}

try:
    # Send the request to the ngrok tunnel URL
    response = requests.post(ngrok_tunnel_url, json=payload)
    
    # Check the response status code
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Request successful:")
        print("Response content:")
        print(response.text)
    else:
        print("Error:", response.status_code)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print("Error:", e)
```

which returns `Error: 403`

Does anyone know how to fix this, or how to properly access a remote instance of Ollama?

Comment: Is there a reason you're importing `pyngrok` but then not using it, and using `run_process` commands instead? All those same commands can be done through the Python package you're import (here's an example of [set auth token](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#setting-the-authtoken)).

Beyond that, it's hard to help troubleshoot when none of the output logs, besides mentioning the 403, are provided.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Set the Host Header to localhost:11434

I had the same issue in both terminal and Python. Setting the flag `--request-header="localhost:11434"` for the ngrok command fixed both for me.

I think the 403 occurs because the incoming requests are still not routed correctly by the tunnel. It was recently added to [Ollama FAQ](https://github.com/ollama/ollama/blob/main/docs/faq.md).

Here's the updated server code:

```
await asyncio.gather(
    run_process(['ollama', 'serve']),
    run_process(['ngrok', 'http', '--log', 'stderr', '11434', '--host-header="localhost:11434"']), # Set host header
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, running this still returns Error 404. I think it might have something to do with being able to locally connect to the remote machine via ngrok, as it keeps saying access is denied even fro curl statements.