Cannot run Ollama with Google Colab via ngrok
I am following the steps shown here, however I am unable to get the output:
>>> starting ollama serve
Couldn't find '/root/.ollama/id_ed25519'. Generating new private key.
Your new public key is:

ssh-ed25519 {some key}

2024/01/16 20:19:11 images.go:808: total blobs: 0
2024/01/16 20:19:11 images.go:815: total unused blobs removed: 0
2024/01/16 20:19:11 routes.go:930: Listening on 127.0.0.1:11434 (version 0.1.20)

But, I am getting only the following output
>>> starting ollama serve 
time=2024-05-03T07:49:48.426Z level=INFO source=images.go:828 msg="total blobs: 0"
time=2024-05-03T07:49:48.426Z level=INFO source=images.go:835 msg="total unused blobs removed: 0"
time=2024-05-03T07:49:48.426Z level=INFO source=routes.go:1071 msg="Listening on 127.0.0.1:11434 (version 0.1.33)"
time=2024-05-03T07:49:48.427Z level=INFO source=payload.go:30 msg="extracting embedded files" dir=/tmp/ollama3694758245/runners

Also when running ollama in the terminal I am getting this error: Error: something went wrong, please see the ollama server logs for details
Any idea what might be wrong?
PS: I tried both examples shown in here

I was able to solve it by following the suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78181401/how-to-locally-access-an-ollama-model-remotely-hosted-on-a-google-colab-for-a-py
